# Umbraco URL issue with Vorto

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using vorto plugin in my Umbraco 7 application to achieve the multilingual capability.

I mentioned the URL in hostname as 'localhost/clientname/en'.

Whenever I open login page the URL which is getting form is 'http://localhost/clientname/en/login'. 
This is the structure of vorto URL writing.

But can I achieve it like 'http://localhost/clientname/login/en' ???

I want language names at the end of the URL, not in between.

Is it possible ?

Please help....i am badly stuck in my project task !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a custom URL provider, setting the domain to 'localhost/clientname/en' will mean that the URLs will always get added AFTER the language part as the host is always the first part of the URL.

Have a look at this article on URL providers and content finders: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/ it's quite old, but it should still work. That should give you an idea of how to make it work. Basically you want the URL provider to append the language to the end of the URL, and the content finder to strip the language from the end and then find the actual content. You can also then set the language of the current thread in the content finder so that Vorto and Umbraco are using the correct language based on the URL.